# how to print 0 for specific key if key doesnt exist in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like below, as you see I am  trying to print `key_p` which is not in dictionary. I want to check if my `key_p` exist in dictionary, print the value and when the `key_p` is not in dictionary print `0`.

when I put condition `elif`, it will print two times `0` ( =  the number of element in the dictionary) but I just want to check only `key_p`, meaning if the `key_p` is in the dictionary print `1` if only `key_p` is not in the dictionary print `0`.

```
sc={'sen': 1,'lag': 1 }

key_p="tep"

for field, values in sc.items():

   if field==key_p:

      print("1")

   elif field!=key_p:

      print ("0")
```

Comment: generally: `d.get(k, 0)`. Google `python get dictionary method`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` to check if key in dict.

**Ex:**

```
sc={'sen': 1,'lag': 1 }
if "tep" in sc:
    print("1")
else:
    print("0")
```

or if one line use `dict.get`.

**Ex:**

```
print(sc.get("tep", "0"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sc={'sen': 1,'lag': 1 }

sc.get('tep') or '0'

#out
0
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.